# Upgrading from Powershell 2.0 to Powershell 5.1

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I'm stuck trying to upgrade from PS 2 to PS 5.1.

I've been advised to download the WMF 5.1 to do this.

I've run the pre-req script without issue. When the installer then runs, I get error code 0x80240037 (hardware not supported). I have colleagues here with the same hardware who have been able to install PS 5.1 without issue.

I'm on .NET 4.6.2. I have 4.5.2 already installed. WMF 3.0 isn't installed.

x64 bit Windows 7 Pro

Anyone know where I can see more logging information about the failure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 0x80240037 = WU_E_NOT_SUPPORTED (The functionality for the operation is not supported.) look inside the CBS.log from C:\windows\logs\CBS\ to see which operation failed.

Comment: Hi magicandre1981,

Thanks for your response - much appreciated.

Here is a link to the logs generated when I try and run the installer.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K1uIJ4Zi7z8Cmria-ntOLY1b6Q-NhUxK

Would you mind taking a look and letting me know what you think?

Cheers.

Comment: the log doesn't include anything with error. Delete all files from the CBS folder, try to install powershell and share the new log

Comment: Hi again. Cleared down the log file and ran WMF5.1 installer again. The results are the same as before. Seems to be failing when asking for applicability of an update - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Et5Jjr-P8Fi0FNEP_pLFN71V12ZIInOy

Comment: this is the whole file? also share the **windowsupdate.log** from C:\Windows\

Comment: Hi. This was the whole file, after I cleared it down, then ran the update ( 
Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64.zip)

Comment: I've uploaded a capture of the logs generated on windowsupdate.log when running this installer. Saying my processor is not supported? I know my colleagues have the same hardware with this installed...

 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dMXKIUXA-g8WcASEhHBOPcBfDwfOLASq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in the wu.log I see code 80248014 (WU_E_DS_UNKNOWNSERVICE - An operation did not complete because the service is not in the data store.). Stop WU service, rename the folder C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution to C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.old, start WU service and try to install Powershell.

Comment: does this work or not?

Comment: magicandre1981 - Hi there. Thanks for your help on this. What I did in the end was this;

- open .msu installer via 7-zip
- extracted the cabs to another directory
- opened a command prompt in said directory
- run dism command against each cab -DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:Windows6.1-KB3191566-x64.cab

There's a text file in the installer dictating the order in which they should be installed. The third cab wouldn't install. The rest did. I was asked to restart after the final cab installed. Rebooted and PS5.1

Thank you for your help *magicandre1981* - appreciated

Comment: ok, post your steps as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did in the end was this;

- open .msu installer via 7-zip - extracted the cabs to another
  directory
- opened a command prompt in said directory
- run dism command against each cab;

  ```
  DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:Windows6.1-KB3191566-x64.cab
  ```

There's a text file in the installer dictating the order in which they should be installed. The third cab wouldn't install. The rest did. I was asked to restart after the final cab installed. Rebooted and PS5.1

Answer (score 1):

If your CPU is 7. or 8. gen. Intel or Ryzen (AMD), the Microsoft blocks Windows 7/8.1 updates from 04.2017. In this case, the powershell (WMF5.1, 4, 3) installers didn't run, the solution is wufuc (https://github.com/zeffy/wufuc).

Comment: This answer is applicable to the author's situation.  There is an existing [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1306946/is-there-any-issue-running-windows-7-on-an-7th-gen-intel-cpu-kaby-lake) that already suggests this particular program.

Comment: Thanks so much. Was getting that error number and wufuc fixed it for me.